Use pytest-bdd’s tags (Cucumber) to “multiplex” fixtures
I think what I’m really asking is for someone more familiar with pytest’s advanced features or operation to make a suggestion, rather than something specific to pytest-bdd…
To explain the goal:
We would like to use the tagging language of Cucumber (eg. @uat @dev) - which turn into pytest marks - as a way of generating scenario parametrisation.
In this example, adding @uat @dev to a scenario, would then run the scenario test twice with different environment credentials as a fixture.
Another set of tags might also pass slightly different request bodies to match customer-specifics, or dictate that certain scenarios only apply to that customer’s data format.
Problems/what I’ve tried already:

Using fixtures with params has promise as it is a simple pattern and easy to understand. But the params are defined “statically” (unless I’m missing some way to manipulate the params at runtime?)

The idea might be to have a fixture with all possible credential sets, and then look at the scenario’s tags at runtime, somehow returning only a subset of those environments
Not sure if there’s a clever way to do this…?


I’ve tried metafunc with pytest_generate_tests and the request fixture

I will have to come back with the error (which was a little cryptic)
But if I’m understanding it correctly, it is saying that the request object is not available in the pytest_generate_tests hook - probably because generating tests and collection happens before fielding the testing request, which would make sense



I imagine there’s a way of filtering down an exhaustive set of environments at runtime, once the request fixture is available, given an appropriate hook - but perhaps I can be steered towards this?
Many thanks.

Solution
pytest's collection is well defined, and not easy to bypass - there might be a cleaner way which solves the matter of test collection counts. See discussion below.
The solution I've used was to add marks to the environment parameters:
@pytext.fixture(
    params=[
        pytest.param("dev env vars", marks=pytest.mark.env_dev),
        pytest.param("uat env vars", marks=pytest.mark.env_uat),
    ]
)
def env(request):...

And then use similarly-named tags in the Cucumber .feature file - @dev, @uat.
Then in conftest.py:
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items, config):
    for item in items:
        env_param = [m for m in item.keywords if m.startswith("env_")][0]  # Should be just one - the current environment's params
        env_tag = env_param.replace("env_", "")  # The tag we are looking for
        if env_tag not in item.keywords:
            item.add_marker(pytest.mark.skip("This test is not tagged for this environment"))

Discussion and drawback
This works in the way intended, and is reasonably clean to implement; the only condition is each category of marks needs to match some pattern (like the starting characters).
Unfortunately because all possible combinations of test and environment are still collected/parametrised, the total number of tests reported is higher than the true case.
It may be possible to change this behaviour with deeper customisation of the test collection phase.
